# React BootstrapTable NO se actualiza después de actualizar una columna desde un modal y hacer SetState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Cuando selecciono un elemento de una tabla en Modal actualizo unos campos en la lista de la tabla principal, y se refleja el cambio en la lista pero no se renderiza en la tabla donde se muestra la lista, ¿a alguien le ha pasado esto? por favor su ayuda!

```
const selectModalTree = undefined;
                    const listCuentasCont = this.state.listCuentasCont;
                    let indexC = this.state.indexC;
                    const listCCont = listCuentasCont.filter(item => item.ID == selectedCuenta.node.value);

                    let listaCtaOficina = this.state.listaCtaOficina;
                    listaCtaOficina[indexC].CtaContable = listCCont[0].ID;
                    listaCtaOficina[indexC].CtaContableStr = listCCont[0].Cuenta;
                    listaCtaOficina[indexC].CtaContableNom = listCCont[0].Nombre;
                    selectedCuenta = undefined;
                    indexC = -1;
                    this.setState({ selectedCuenta, selectModalTree,indexC, listaCtaOficina });
```

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para asi poder ayudarte mejor, sube el codigo con el que estas trabajando.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Es necesario que compartas el código de lo que estás intentando. Explicando con detalle el problema, el error y el resultado deseado. Puedes usar las herramientas del sitio para que copies y pegues tu código. Saludos

Comment: `y se refleja el cambio en la lista pero no se renderiza en la tabla donde se muestra la lista` que??? tendras que explicar mejor lo que estas haciendo, que variables(props) estas manejando al hacer el cambio y cual al mostrar la "tabla-listas" ¿que?, espero que lo expliques mejor para poder ayudarte

Comment: Me refiero a que el cambio en la lista de datos internamente si se refleja al depurar o mostrar en consola pero no se actualiza en la vista del BootstrapDataTable, se muestra hasta que se hace alguna accion sobre la tabla, como paginar o hacer click sobre la celda

Answer (score 0):

Si el componente de *React Bootstrap Table*, no tiene ningun bug, indicaria que si no se observa ningun cambio al actualizar el estado es porque nada cambio.

Por ejemplo, en su caso puede suceder que `listCCont[0]` sea igual a `listaCtaOficina[indexC]`. Para descartar que no sea un bug del *component Tabla*, intenta crear otra funcion que actualice los datos de *listaCtaOficina*, si cambia entonces su algoritmo no actualiza la informacion como esperas.